# Android P2P file transfer

Tags: android, p2p

Android : Hey I'm trying to develop a peer to peer Android application that enables the users to exchange files (photos, videos or any other file) over the WiFi without a central server i.e. an android device will act as both a client and a server. I'm a bit of a novice at Android so I wanted to ask where to start from?

Answer (score 1):

This is really non-trivial. You have to:

1. Learn how to establish a TCP server/client flow.
2. Possibly learn how to use UDP broadcasting to autodiscover targets.

This [example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) may help.